# Detect ul length is change

Tags: jquery, html

I have `ul`, `li` of it adding by ajax. How to count `li` on change it quantity?

I try

```
(function($) {
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $(document).on('change', 'ul.cart_list', function() {
          alert('Textarea changed');
        });

      }

    });

})(jQuery);
```

Also i have a funcion that counts li, but on reloading of page

```
(function($) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
      function showpanel() {
        var numrelated = $('#nicdark_menu_icon ul.cart_list > li.mini_cart_item').length;
        $('.num-relatedelements').html(numrelated);
      }
      setTimeout(showpanel, 1500);
    })(jQuery);
```

How to detect ul li length is changes without reloading? I need to count li on change and rewrite value of  `$('.num-relatedelements')`

Answer (score 0):

you should calculate the `li` on ajax success function.

Comment: Html is changing, why i should calculate the li on ajax success function? I think if Html is changing it is possible to count it

Comment: but html is changing through ajax response so you have to calculate.

Comment: If i dont know where is this ajax?